# Need help with understand AppController class in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I passed through few basic tutorials of CakePHP. Now I'm trying to understand Authentication Component.

Why in this tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/pl/view/643/Preparing-to-Add-Auth
they create new class AppController? I ask because I've just created some controllers where classes inherited from AppController class and I haven't had the own AppController class yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new AppController to define new extended functionality for your controllers.

Basically all your controllers should extend your new AppController class, which defines all your authentication logic. These beforeFilter()/afterFilter() methods are run automatically by your dispatcher and these methods can dictate whether or not to continue processing the current controller.

Comment: So when I passed through tutorials where I didn't create AppController class (app_controller.php in /app directory), all controllers I created extended another (built-in) AppController class?

Comment: Yes, create the app_controller.php file in your app directory, and all your controllers should extend AppController

Comment: I think you don't understand me (my english is not so good). If I create the app_controller.php file (with AppController class) in my app directory I overwrite AppController class from another file?

Comment: If you already have an app_controller.php in your app directory, then you do not need to overwrite it. Basically you just want to merge the two files together by adding the functionality defined in the tutorial with your existing AppController.

Comment: @latata: If you don't have an app_controller.php in your app directory, CakePHP will use cake/libs/controller/app_controller.php

Answer (score 0):

> Next we need to make some
>   modifications to AppController. If you
>   don't have /app/app_controller.php,
>   create it. Note that this goes in
>   /app/, not /app/controllers/. Since we
>   want our entire site controlled with
>   Auth and Acl, we will set them up in
>   AppController.

In this example, you are simply making modifications (adding a `beforeFilter()` callback) to the "skeleton" AppController class.  This class will be extended by all of the controllers in your app.  It's a way to add functionality that applies to all controllers in your app.